# Core Data: Group by and count results returns empty list

Tags: core-data, ios7, nspredicate, nsexpression, nsattributedescription

Consider the following Core Data entity:

**Person** - personId: NSNumber, *name*: NSString, *position*: NSString

Using Core Data, I'm trying to replicate the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT `position`, COUNT(*) FROM `Person` GROUP BY `position`
```

Below is the objective-c equivalent:

```c
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"]

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"position"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSAttributeDescription *positionDescription = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"position"];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

[expressionDescription setName:@"count"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[positionDescription, expressionDescription]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[positionDescription]];
[request setResultType: NSDictionaryResultType];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest: request error: &error];
```

The Person entity is definitely populated, however, when executing the above code, the `results` array is empty.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do you get an *empty array* or *nil*? If you get nil  then the error variable should contain some information.

Comment: Have you *saved* the objects before executing the request? A fetch request with NSDictionaryResultType returns only the objects from the store file. - Do you get results if you omit the setPropertiesToGroupBy?

Comment: The objects are definitely saved.

Comment: I just ran a small test app with your code, and it worked and produced the expected results.

Comment: Looks like that was it.  While using MagicalRecord and CoreData, I didn't do the MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait], but instead I was using [NSManagedObjectContext save:] operation. Also, I didn't know that a fetch request with NSDictionaryResultType returns only the data from the store file.  Thanks @MartinR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From my above comments:)   A fetch request with `NSDictionaryResultType` returns only the objects from the store file, not the pending changes. Therefore you have to save the context to the persistent store before executing that fetch request.

Comment: Can you give me or point me to an examples where i can get all the entities grouped by a particular attribute?